# Java - Else If loop will NOT work with instance variable

Tags: java

I'm attempting to calculate how much tax a user should pay, based on wage. For example, calculating 20% in the first `if` loop, this will be saved in `generaltax`:

```
    int generalTax = 0;
    int userGrossPay = 50000;
    if (userGrossPay <= 10600) {generalTax += 0;} 
    else if (((userGrossPay >= 10600) && (userGrossPay <= 31785))) { generalTax =  ((20/100) * userGrossPay); } 
    else if (((userGrossPay >= 31786) && (userGrossPay <= 150000))) { generalTax =  ((40/100) * userGrossPay); System.out.println(generalTax);} 
    else if (userGrossPay > 150001) {generalTax = ((45/100) * userGrossPay); }
    else{System.out.println("error");};

    userGrossPay -= generalTax;
    System.out.println(userGrossPay);
```

However `generalTax` pay is for some reason always stuck as `0` and is not properly updating on each iteration.

Comment: `if` is not commonly characterized as a 'loop'. Also note that when you are dividing you want to be using `float` and not `int`. The quickest way to debug this is to put 'print' statements in each clause of your `if` statement, and determine if that clause is being reached.

Comment: @ATGuy I have some other information for you. Take a look below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is that you are always adding `0` or assigning `0` to `generalTax`.

For example, `(20/100) * userGrossPay` is `0`, since `20/100` is `0` due to `int` division. Change it too `0.2 * userGrossPay` or `20.0/100 * userGrossPay`. Similarly change all other places where you divide two integers.

Comment: Thank you VERY much Eran, you solved my problem. Just to clarify what do you mean by "int division"; thank you.

Comment: @ATGuy When you are dividing two integers, such as 20 / 100, the result is an integer. Since there are no fractions in integers, the result is 0. On the other hand, if you change it to 20.0 / 100, you are dividing a double by an integer, which would result in floating point division and return 0.2.

Comment: Thank you Eran, I appreciate you helping me so much i'll make a mental note to remeber your advice next time.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by integer division.

If you mix floating data type with integer, it will give you a data conversion by promotion.

For example:

```
    int num = 5;
    System.out.println(num / 2);    //Gives you 2
    System.out.println(num / 2.0);  //Gives you 2.5
    System.out.println(num * 2);    //Gives you 10
    System.out.println(num * 2.0);  //Gives you 10.0
    System.out.println(num + 2.5);  //Gives you 7.5
```

If all operands in the operation are integers, your output will be integer as well. This is how you got into an integer division accidentally.

```
((20/100) * userGrossPay);
```

I see that you already accepted Eran's answer and understood what went wrong, I am here to give you some additional information.

Comment: Thank you user, I was getting stuck because when I used a calculator my formula seemed to be fine, which was why I was so confused. Thanks for the advice